# i tried this code but it did not work, what should i change?

Tags: python-3.x

i wrote this solution to the problem:

The function should create a new empty list and add every element from **`lst`** that has an odd index. The function should then return this new list.

For example, **`odd_indices([4, 3, 7, 10, 11, -2])`** should return the list **`[3, 10, -2]`**.

solution:  i'm a beginner, i can't understand why this returns 10 only instead of 3, 10, -2.

```
def odd_indices(lst):
  new_lst = []
  for i in lst:
    if i % 2 != 0:
      new_lst.append(lst[i])
      return new_lst
```

```
#this is python 3
def odd_indices(lst):
  new_lst = []
  for i in lst:
    if i % 2 != 0:
      new_lst.append(lst[i])
      return new_lst
```

Comment: Please edit your title to be a meaningfule description of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`return` makes the function exit immediately. Un-indent the return statement so it is not inside the for loop.

```
def odd_indices(lst):
  new_lst = []
  for i in lst:
    if i % 2 != 0:
      new_lst.append(lst[i])
  return new_lst  # <---------- unindent here
```